# What is the equivalent of a tree for directed graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, trees, directed-graphs

A *tree* is defined as a connected acyclic *undirected* graph at page 171 of this [online book](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~gill/BWLectSite/Resources/LDGbookCOV.pdf).

What is the equivalent of a tree for directed graphs? A connected acyclic *directed* graph (i.e. a connected DAG)? In other words, what is a *directed tree*? If you have a good reference I am really interested.

Comment: Maybe a *rooted tree* where there is a root vertex $r$ so that all edges are aligned in the direction away from $r$. (or toward $r$, if you prefer.)

Comment: @JairTaylor The directed tree that you describe is not connected (take two sibblings for instance), but it is weakly connected. But do we even need a root for directed trees? (Undirected) trees are not always rooted.

Comment: @Maggyero If you are asking for a directed graph to be strongly connected, it will certainly not be acyclic.

Comment: You may refer to Ch. 9 of [Graph Theory by Narsingh Deo](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.edutechlearners.com/download/Graphtheory.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiJxNu4sJviAhVJnI8KHdDXDnMQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw1oEyD8aExwHjBnUD4db8cH)

Comment: @MishaLavrov I was refererring to connected graphs (there is a directed path from *u* to *v* **or** from *v* to *u* for every pair of vertices *u*, *v*), not strongly-connected graphs (there is a directed path from *u* to *v* **and** from *v* to *u* for every pair of vertices *u*, *v*).

Comment: @Maggyero This is not a common definition of "connected" for directed graphs. Under your definition, the only directed graphs that are both connected and acyclic are the directed paths.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I have found it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)#Definitions_of_components,_cuts_and_connectivity). But there is no reference. So the common definition of connected is weakly connected?

Comment: Usually, either weakly connected or strongly connected can be considered, but here strongly connected will not help.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks, that's exactly what I have just read in [Narshingh Deo's book](http://www.edutechlearners.com/download/Graphtheory.pdf). Wikipedia articles on graph theory are such a mess.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Thank you very much, the book answered all my questions (see below).

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help

Comment: The definition of a directed tree should not dictate what you do. You should start with the problem you are trying to solve, and let that decide what the right definition of a directed tree should be!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of Narsingh Deo’s book [*Graph Theory with Applications to Engineering and Computer Science*](http://www.edutechlearners.com/download/Graphtheory.pdf) (thank you @ShubhamJohri for the reference) I could answer to myself:

Section 9.4. Directed paths and connectedness:

> Walks, paths, and circuits in a directed graph, in addition to being what they are in the corresponding undirected graph, have the added consideration of orientation. […]
>
> A *directed walk* from a vertex *v<sub>i</sub>* to *v<sub>j</sub>* is an alternating sequence of vertices and edges, beginning with *v<sub>i</sub>* and ending with *v<sub>j</sub>*, such that each edge is oriented from the vertex preceding it to the vertex following it. Of course, no edge in a directed walk appears more than once, but a vertex may appear more than once, just as in the case of undirected graphs. A *semiwalk* in a directed graph is a walk in the corresponding undirected graph, but is *not* a *directed walk*. A *walk* in a digraph can mean either a directed walk or a semiwalk.
>
> The definitions of *circuit*, *semicircuit*, and *directed circuit* can be written similarly. […]
>
> *Connected Digraphs*: In Chapter 2 a graph (i.e., undirected graph) was defined as connected if there was at least one path between every pair of vertices. In a digraph, there are two different types of paths. Consequently, we have two different types of connectedness in digraphs. A digraph *G* is said to be *strongly connected* if there it at least one directed path from every vertex to every other vertex. A digraph *G* is said to be *weakly connected* if its corresponding undirected graph is connected but *G* is not strongly connected. […] The statement that a digraph *G* is connected simply means that its corresponding undirected graph is connected; and thus *G* may be strongly or weakly connected. A directed graph that is not connected is dubbed as disconnected.

Section 9.6. Trees with directed edges:

> A tree (for undirected graphs) was defined as a connected graph without any circuit. The basic concept as well as the term “tree” remains the same for digraphs. A *tree* is a connected digraph that has no circuit—neither a directed circuit nor a semicircuit. A tree of *n* vertices contains *n − 1* directed edges and has properties similar to those with undirected edges. […]
>
> *Arborescence*: A digraph *G* is said to be an arborescence if
>
> 1. *G* contains no circuit—neither directed nor semicircuit.
> 2. In *G* there is precisely one vertex *v* of zero in-degree.
>
> This vertex *v* is called the *root of the arborescence*. […]
>
> THEOREM 9.2. An arborescence is a tree in which every vertex other than the root has an in-degree of exactly one.
>
> […]
>
> An arborescence is in a sense a tree directed out of the root. Therefore an arborescence is sometimes referred to as an *out-tree*. (Reversing the direction of every edge in an arborescence will produce what may be called an *in-tree*.)

Section 9.11. Acyclic digraphs and decyclization:

> In many situations semicircuits are of no significance, and one is concerned only with whether or not a given digraph has a directed circuit. A digraph that has no directed circuit is called *acyclic*.

To sum up, for directed graphs:

- a *connected directed graph* is either a strongly connected directed graph or a weakly connected directed graph;
- a *cycle* is either a directed cycle or a semicycle;
- an *acyclic directed graph* (DAG) is a directed graph without *directed* cycles;
- a *directed tree* is a connected directed graph without cycles (not to be confused with a connected directed graph without *directed* cycles—a connected DAG). In other words, it is a directed graph whose underlying graph is a tree;
- an *arborescence* (or *out-tree*) is a directed tree whose vertices have a maximum in-degree of 1;
- an *anti-arborescence* (or *in-tree*) is a directed tree whose vertices have a maximum out-degree of 1.

For instance, this connected DAG is not a directed tree: ({*a*, *b*, *c*}, {(*a*, *b*), (*b*, *c*), (*a*, *c*)}), since even if it is connected (more precisely weakly connected) it has semicycles, for instance (*a*, (*a*, *b*), *b*, (*b*, *c*), *c*, (*a*, *c*), *a*).

---

Likewise, for directed graphs:

- a *directed forest* is a directed graph without cycles (not to be confused with an acyclic directed graph, i.e. a DAG). In other words, it is a directed graph whose underlying graph is a forest.
- a *branching* (or *out-forest*) is a directed forest whose vertices have a maximum in-degree of 1;
- an *anti-branching* (or *in-forest*) is a directed forest whose vertices have a maximum out-degree of 1.

Another convention calls a directed tree a *polytree*, an arborescence a *directed tree*, a directed forest a *polyforest* and a branching a *directed forest*.

Cf. the [documentation of NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/tree/recognition.html), a Python library.